# Find range of td's between two elements of a class Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to refine my parsing of a web page scrape. I can see my crude methods aren't reliable because I'm counting the numbers of pairs of **class="descript"** and **class="data"**, and sort of doing a one-to-one pairing of these. But I notice some of my database records aren't matching, and it looks like some sections of the page will give multiple (and unknown *n*) number of **class="data"** per any one instance of **class="descript"**.

For example, take this chunk of code (all fake names and addresses), where I want to grab all the tds with class="data" that lie between

```
 <tr><td><span class="heading">Name And Address of Judgment Creditor (Plaintiff)</span></td></tr>
```

...and...

```
 <tr><td><span class="heading">Name And Address of Judgment Debtor(s) (Defendant(s))</span></td></tr>
```

Here's the sample chunk of code I want to grab all three defendants and their addresses, for a single plaintiff:

```
<tr><td><span class="heading">Name And Address of Judgment Creditor (Plaintiff)</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class="data">FAKE NAME<br>
501 N.W. STUPID STREET<br>
JERKY BOY, FL 12345<br>
</td></tr>
<tr><td><span class="heading">Name And Address of Judgment Debtor(s (Defendant(s))</span></td></tr>
<tr><td class="data">
BIMBO, IM A<br>2001 11TH AVENUE EAST, STE 32<br>LAKE CLEAR, FL 33333 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="data">
ADVANCED PAIN & SPINAL REHABILITATION, INC.<br>2001 10TH AVENUE NORTH, SUITE 2<br>LAKE WORTH, FL 33461 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="data">10TH AVE. HEALTH CARE CENTER, INC.<br>2001 10TH AVENUE NORTH, SUITE 2<br>LAKE WORTH, FL 33461 </td></tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)?

Comment: Xpath to select them `//td[following::td/span[@class="heading"]  and  preceding::td/span[@class="heading"]]`

Comment: @sebastianForsberg I haven't, but am reading about it now. What is the advantage over simple html dom parse, since the html source is infuriatingly irregular, with no id's to make it easier?

Comment: You can actually use xpath with simple but it doesn't always work. Try [this one](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) if you want better support.

Answer (score 1):

If you do decide to use DomDocument, here you find Xpath which select the items you want (I've splitted it for ease reading) :

```
//td[@class="data"]
    [following::td/span[@class="heading"]  and  preceding::td/span[@class="heading"]]
```